# How can i secure this PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to secure this PHP script from sql injection:

```
 <?php
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
$lastmsg = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['lastmsg']);
$result=mysql_query("select * from messages where msg_id<'$lastmsg' order by msg_id desc limit 9");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$msg_id=$row['ms_gid'];
$message=$row['message'];
?>



<li>[
<?php echo $message; ?>
</li>


<?php
}


?>

<div id="more<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="morebox">
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="more">more</a>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: is 'lastmsg' a POST or GET variable?  You've referenced it two different ways.

Comment: Its a post, sorry just noticed that. Thanks :)

Comment: **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**. Learn it, use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$lastmsg = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['lastmsg']);
```

If you have access to mysqli you should use it in preference to mysql, because it allows you to bind parameters to statements thus bypassing SQL injection attacks. Sample code in procedural style:

```
$link = mysqli_connect();
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "select * from messages where msg_id < ? order by msg_id desc limit 9");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET['lastmsg']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
$count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is the only thing you need. Pass any value you're going to insert into the database through that first.

```
$someval = mysql_real_escape_string($someval);
$query = "SELECT ... WHERE field='$someval'";
```